# How to train a ANFIS model with membership function of a particular input as "NONE" or "ZERO"

Tags: matlab, input, fuzzy-logic

I have trained an ANFIS model in MATLAB using inputs with 3 membership functions each. The membership functions are "LOW", 'AVERAGE" and "HIGH". Now I wish to add one more membership function as "NONE" or "ZERO", where when it is used, the particular input will not be activated. Is this possible?

Comment: "when "DON'T CARE" is used, the particular input will not be activated." Than you do care. You want "NONE" or "ZERO". If you dont care, then it will do whatever it does, *you dont care what it does*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You're right, I meant "NONE" or "ZERO". I have edited my question.